# Setting up a many-to-many relationship in Active Record

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two models: `meal_plans` and `dinners`.  Each `meal_plan` will have a week's worth of `dinners`, and each dinner will be on, potentially, several `meal_plans`.

I'm wondering what the best approach is to save 7 dinner IDs into a meal plan.  Initially, I was just going to save an array of dinner IDs into a meal plan's params with a helper:

```
    def create_week_of_meals(week) 
        ids = []
        week.each {|dinner| ids.push(dinner.id)}
        return ids
    end
```

With strong params:

`params.require(:meal_plan).permit(:user_id, :meals)`

This works alright, but it leaves me with a string of meal_ids which I would have to turn back into an array and then query `Dinners` for each one of those dinner ids. Is there a better way of doing this?  I've seen a lot of references to rails `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but from what I can tell that mostly deals with saving some attributes from another model into the current record, whereas I'm looking to save a reference to several models.
I am familiar with has_many_through relationships but it seems like a lot of overhead to create a separate model and seven new records for each meal plan just to attach some `dinner_ids` to a record.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dinner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meal_plan_placements
  has_many :meal_plans, through: :meal_plan_placements
end

class MealPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meal_plan_placements
  has_many :dinners, through: :meal_plan_placements
end

class MealPlanPlacement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dinner
  belongs_to :meal_plan
end
```

This should work, but I haven't actually run it locally, so you should play around with it. You can also [read more about the `through` option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, my question was more about if has_many through was the right approach for something like this rather than how to set one up but I appreciate your answer and I'm assuming you'd say this is the way to go for the particular situation I'm facing?

Comment: Yes. I would  go with as much convention as possible until you have a clear understanding of why to diverge from the convention. I try to always ask my self the question: Am I storing information, or am i storing data. Those two are not the same.